# GDAL Python - Warping Raster with Inaccurate GPS data (GCPs)

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I'm currently working to georeference a raster (GTiff, output by Metashape) using inaccurate GPS points (serving as GCPs). I have some code that works well, in that it places the raster the in the right location (EPSG 32655), and the rotation and scale are approximately correct. However, because the GPS points are not "accurate" it results in the raster being warped something bad. If I use all GPS points, the raster comes out horribly, however, if I use a linear regression model to estimate a bounding box around the raster, it comes out better, but still pretty stretched.

**Background:** If you've worked with Metashape before, I'm essentially creating a planar (topXY view) orthomosaic in local coordinates to create the "best looking" orthomosaic, and then trying to place it in the approximately correct location using these inaccurate GPS points with GDAL python. If you're wondering why I don't just use the GPS points as reference data in Metashape, it's because Metashape will not allow you to carry over GPS data when creating a planar (topXY view) orthomosaic, and this is what I need.

**My question is:** are there any recommendations for using GDAL python bindings to perform essentially affine-only transformations to get the raster in the **approximately** correct location (with regards to provided GPS points)? The most important factors are approximate location, scale, rotation, and preserving the original appearance of the raster. Previously the rotation of the raster was a difficulty, but the code was able to solve that, but the trade-off now being warping.

Any suggestions are extremely appreciated!

Below is working code, just need to figure out how to reduce warping:

```py
# Path the georeferencing information, drop not aligned
df = pd.read_csv(georeference_path, index_col=0)
df = df[['Easting', 'Northing', 'x_pixels', 'y_pixels']].dropna()

# Extract the features (pixel values) and targets (Easting, Northing coordinates)
X = df[['x_pixels', 'y_pixels']].values
y = df[['Easting', 'Northing']].values

# Create a linear regression model
model = LinearRegression()

# Fit the model to the data
model.fit(X, y)

# Open the source dataset and add GCPs to it
src_ds = gdal.OpenShared(str(src_path), gdal.GA_Update)
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(32655)
src_ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())

# Get the height and width of the image
width = src_ds.RasterYSize
height = src_ds.RasterXSize

# Calculate the coordinates of the four corners and the center
top_left = (0, 0)
bottom_left = (0, height)
bottom_right = (width, height)
top_right = (width, 0)
center = (width // 2, height // 2)

# Calculate the coordinates of the center of each line
line_left = (0, height // 2)
line_bottom = (width // 2, height)
line_right = (width, height // 2)
line_top = (width // 2, 0)

pixels = np.array([top_left,
                   bottom_left,
                   bottom_right,
                   top_right,
                   center,
                   line_left,
                   line_bottom,
                   line_right,
                   line_top])

# Convert pixel coordinates to Easting and Northing using the linear regression model
easting, northing = model.predict(pixels).T

# Print the predicted coordinates
for i, coord in enumerate(list(zip(easting, northing))):
    print(f"Corner {i + 1}: Easting={coord[0]}, Northing={coord[1]}")

# Plot the data
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df['Easting'].values, df['Northing'].values, c='blue')
plt.scatter(easting, northing, c='green')
plt.show()

gcps = []

# Iterate over each row in the DataFrame
for _, row in df.iterrows():

    # Create a new GCP object
    gcp = gdal.GCP()
    gcp.GCPX = row['Easting']
    gcp.GCPY = row['Northing']
    gcp.GCPZ = 0.0
    gcp.GCPPixel = row['x_pixels']
    gcp.GCPLine = row['y_pixels']

    # Add the GCP to the list
    gcps.append(gcp)


# Iterate over each row in the DataFrame
for i, pixel_coord in enumerate(pixels):
    # Create a new GCP object
    gcp = gdal.GCP()
    gcp.GCPX = easting[i]
    gcp.GCPY = northing[i]
    gcp.GCPZ = 0.0
    gcp.GCPPixel = int(pixel_coord[0])
    gcp.GCPLine = int(pixel_coord[1])

    # Add the GCP to the list
    gcps.append(gcp)

gcp_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
gcp_srs.ImportFromEPSG(32655)
gcp_crs_wkt = gcp_srs.ExportToWkt()
src_ds.SetGCPs(gcps, gcp_crs_wkt)

# Define target SRS
dst_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
dst_srs.ImportFromEPSG(32655)
dst_wkt = dst_srs.ExportToWkt()

error_threshold = 0.5  # error threshold --> use same value as in gdalwarp
resampling = gdal.GRA_Lanczos

# Call AutoCreateWarpedVRT() to fetch default values for target raster dimensions and geotransform
tmp_ds = gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(src_ds,
                                  None,  # src_wkt : left to default value --> will use the one from source
                                  dst_wkt,
                                  resampling,
                                  error_threshold)
dst_xsize = tmp_ds.RasterXSize
dst_ysize = tmp_ds.RasterYSize
dst_gt = tmp_ds.GetGeoTransform()
tmp_ds = None

# Now create the true target dataset
dst_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(dst_path,
                                              dst_xsize,
                                              dst_ysize,
                                              src_ds.RasterCount)
                                              # options=['COMPRESS=LZW', 'PREDICTOR=2', 'INTERLEAVE=BAND'])
dst_ds.SetProjection(dst_wkt)
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(dst_gt)
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(0)

# And run the reprojection
gdal.ReprojectImage(src_ds,
                    dst_ds,
                    None,  # src_wkt : left to default value --> will use the one from source
                    None,  # dst_wkt : left to default value --> will use the one from destination
                    resampling,
                    0,  # WarpMemoryLimit : left to default value
                    error_threshold,
                    progress_callback,  # Progress callback : function that outputs progress
                    None)  # Progress callback user data
dst_ds = None
print("Done.")
```